# Is there an R function that does the opposite of dplyr::coalesce()?

Tags: r, dplyr

Calling `dplyr::coalesce` returns the first non-missing values:

```
> vec1 <- c(11, 12, NA, NA, NA)
> vec2 <- c(21, 22, NA, NA, 25)
> vec3 <- c(NA, 32, NA, 34, 35)
> coalesce(vec1, vec2, vec3)
[1] 11 12 NA 34 25
```

which is similar to calling `vec1 | vec2 | vec3` (returning values instead of logicals).

Is there a function analogous to `vec1 & vec2 & vec3`, returning the last value when none are missing? This comes up a ton but I can't find a concise/simple way to do it.

```
> vec1 <- c(11, 12, NA, NA, NA)
> vec2 <- c(21, 22, NA, NA, 25)
> vec3 <- c(NA, 32, NA, 34, 35)
> ideal_fn(vec1, vec2, vec3)
[1] NA 32 NA NA NA
```

For numbers and logicals, I can do this easily/concisely with `vec3[vec1 & vec2 & vec3]` or `ifelse(vec1 & vec2, vec3)`. But they don't work with character vectors.

Is there something better than `ifelse(!is.na(vec1) & !is.na(vec2) & !is.na(vec3), vec3, NA)`? Just strikes me as a very roundabout way of solving a very simple problem.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `pmax` without the `na.rm`

```
pmax(vec1, vec2, vec3)
#[1] NA 32 NA NA NA
```

---

Or another option is `max.col` with `ties.method = 'last'`.  Create a matrix or data.frame with the vectors, then apply `max.col` to get the column index of `max` value on each row, `cbind` with sequence of rows and extract the corresponding values.  If a row have only `NA`s, the column index will be `NA` and thus gets `NA`

```
m1 <- cbind(vec1, vec2, vec3)
m1[cbind(seq_len(nrow(m1)), max.col(m1, 'last'))]
#[1] NA 32 NA NA NA
```

If this is based on position and not max values

```
m2 <- col(m1) * NA^is.na(m1)
m1[cbind(seq_len(nrow(m1)), max.col(m2, 'last'))]
#[1] NA 32 NA NA NA
```

---

Or if there are more vectors, another option is to create a the logical vector with `Reduce`

```
i1 <- Reduce(`|`, lapply(mget(paste0("vec", 1:3)), is.na))
replace(vec3, i1, NA)
#[1] NA 32 NA NA NA
```

---

Or using `rowSums`

```
vec3 * NA^!!rowSums(is.na(cbind(vec1, vec2, vec3)))
#[1] NA 32 NA NA NA
```

NOTE: Both are `base R` functions

Comment: It is based on position so `pmax` won't work unfortunately. And I think I'd still go with `ifelse(!is.na(vec1) & !is.na(vec2) & !is.na(vec3), vec3, NA)` over option 2 since it's a little easier to read

Comment: @Nick If it is based on position, I also have edited that case.  Please read the whole solution instead of the first.  If you have more than 10 vectors, then you can change the `&` to `i1 <- Reduce('&', !lapply(mget(paste0("vec", 1:3)), is.na)); ifelse(i1, vec3, NA)`

Answer (score 0):

I messed around and just found a cleaner way using tidyverse:

```
and_values <- . %>%
  reduce(~ ifelse(is.na(.x), NA, .y))

> and_values(list(vec1, vec2, vec3))
[1] NA 32 NA NA NA
```